# Deploy a C# console application to a remote server using Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, console-application

I'm new to deployment and Jenkins. So here I am trying to deploy my simple C# console application (an .exe file) onto a remote server. I'm using Jenkins to do this. So, I configure my Jenkins job to run the following batch command:

```
set EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true
nuget restore
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild" %WORKSPACE%\consoleapp.csproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=server1
```

The Jenkins job gets build successfully. However, the app is not published to the remote server. The %WORKSPACE% refers to my source control workspace and that is configured well. Also, I have a .pubxml file in my console app project specifying the publishURL(path inside the remote server) as well.

I followed the same steps for a web app and it worked like a charm. What is different for a console application?

Comment: AFAIK deployment of web app cannot be applied to ConsoleApplication. I think you have to copy manually the .exe file to remote servers either by WinRM or copy to Shared Folder.

Comment: Yeah, so as of now, I have added a post-build event and written an xcopy command to do a manual copy.